# Disable button from one control in another control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-8

Hi I am working on Win 8 metro app buid in silverlight.

I have two controls Control1 and Control2

Control2 is inside Control1

Control2 has a listview and Control1 has buttons. Clicking on listview has to disable buttons in Control1.

I tried to achieve this from code behind by using

```
 public bool OverriddenFlag
{
    get { return _overriddenFlag; }
    set
    {
        _overriddenFlag= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("OverriddenFlag");
    }
}
```

and in xaml

```
<Button x:Name="ShowDetails" FontWeight="bold" FontSize="12" Content="+" click="ShowDetails_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding OverriddenFlag, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

but it didn't disabled the button.
How can I disable buttons. Any idea?

Comment: You seem to be very confused here. If you're doing a Windows8 Metro app, you're doing neither Silverlight neither Windows Phone 7 (you might be doing XAML and C# though). If you're doing Silverlight app, you're not doing a Windows8 app.

Answer (score 0):

OverridenFlag should be a dependency property in Control2 as so:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverriddenFlagProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OverriddenFlag",
        typeof(bool), typeof(Control2), null);

    public bool OverriddenFlagProperty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(OverriddenFlagProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OverriddenFlagProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Then try modifing your binding to:

```
<Button x:Name="ShowDetails"  IsEnabled="{Binding OverriddenFlag, ElementName=Control2}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have not tried your code yet but i'll try. I did do what i wanted with frameworkelement like this `code`  FrameworkElement fe = (FrameworkElement)this.Parent;
            while (fe.GetType().Name != "Control")
                fe = (FrameworkElement)fe.Parent;

            Button _button = (Button)fe.FindName("button");
            _button.IsEnabled = false;   @Tony

Comment: Hi Tony, I tried like you said but it is not changing the state of the button even when an item is clicked in the control2. In control2 i am setting the OverriddenGlag = true;